# How to return an NSArray in the success block, iOS, Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, block, afnetworking-3

this is my code. I want to return an array with data after data assign from the web service to the array.I have use block to check.
this is from my header file...

```
typedef void(^FailureBlock)(NSError *error);
typedef void(^SuccessBlock) (NSMutableArray *responseArray);
```

this is my implementation file ....

```
- (void)setupConnectionWithsuccess:(SuccessBlock)success failure:(FailureBlock)failure
{
    airportArray = nil;
    NSString *airportCode = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"some code"];
    NSString *authenticationCode = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"some api"];
    NSString *baseurl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"some url",authenticationCode,airportCode];
//    NSString *mainurlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@""];
//    NSURL *mainurl = [NSURL URLWithString:mainurlString];

    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    [manager GET:baseurl parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {

        NSArray *mainArray = (NSArray *)responseObject;

        airportArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (NSDictionary *all in mainArray) {
            airports = [all objectForKey:@"Airport"];

            [airportArray addObject:airports];
            NSLog(@"%@", airports);
        }

        if(success){
            success(airportArray);
        }

        //NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);
    }
    failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {

        if (failure) {
            failure(error);
        }
        UIAlertController *mainAlert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Something Wrong!" message:[error localizedDescription] preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        [self presentViewController:mainAlert animated:YES completion:nil];

    }];




}
```

then after success, I want to return the array from this method.how can I do that

```
- (NSArray *)returnAll
{
    [self setupConnectionWithsuccess:^(NSMutableArray *responseArray) {

    } failure:^(NSError *error) {

    }];
}
```

please help me with this.I'm new to iOS Block.

Comment: What problem did you face?

Comment: And no need to check if(success) and if (failure) because for both blocks are different different.

Comment: You not able to return the anything in the block rather you have to use the block when you receiving the response at calling here in your code 
When you call this 
[self setupConnectionWithsuccess:^(NSMutableArray *responseArray) {
You get your nsmutable array here 
    } failure:^(NSError *error) {

    }];

Comment: I want to return the array after data loaded.So I use returnAll method.in her I want to return the responseArray. I declared a public mutable array and and assinged it to the value of resoponse array in success(inside the returnAll method.) then I return it.after that I print it in viewdidload method.but it prints null

Comment: u can't return array from block because whenever you return any object it will return before you get success or failure so for another time it will not return anything

Answer (score 0):

Try as follow here i use id because in id you can pass anyobject

```
- (void)setupConnectionWithsuccess:(void (^)(id responseObject, NSError *error))completion{
airportArray = nil;
NSString *airportCode = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"some code"];
NSString *authenticationCode = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"some api"];
NSString *baseurl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"some url",authenticationCode,airportCode];
//    NSString *mainurlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@""];
//    NSURL *mainurl = [NSURL URLWithString:mainurlString];

AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
[manager GET:baseurl parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {

    NSArray *mainArray = (NSArray *)responseObject;

    airportArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSDictionary *all in mainArray) {
        airports = [all objectForKey:@"Airport"];

        [airportArray addObject:airports];
        NSLog(@"%@", airports);
    }

    if (completion)
        completion(responseObject,nil);

    //NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);
}
     failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {

         if (completion)
             completion(nil,error);
         UIAlertController *mainAlert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Something Wrong!" message:[error localizedDescription] preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
         [self presentViewController:mainAlert animated:YES completion:nil];

     }];}
```

and to call it

```
[self setupConnectionWithsuccess:^(id responseObject, NSError *error) {
    if (responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"responsceObect");
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

It get nothing while your function return. Because your block excute at asynchonize way. you should modify your function to handle the Array data in a block.